# Subnet Utils cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-commons-net

I have a java code-

```
import org.apache.commons.net.util.*;

public class test {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        SubnetUtils utils = new SubnetUtils("192.168.1.0/24");
        String[] allIps = utils.getInfo().getAllAddresses();
    }
}
```

The apache commons net jar is added to the classpath.

Still I am getting an error for SubnetUtils as it cannot be resolved to a type.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved now.

Checked the class files inside the apache-commons-net.jar and there was no SubnetUtils present. The jar file seems to be of a very old version.

Downloaded a latest jar and everything works fine.